# hadoop map reduce program not running Unsupported major.minor version

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

When I am running my MapReduce program like that:

```
bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/mapreduceprog.jar problemdata /problemdata/input2 /problemdata/output5
```

I get the following output:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: mapreduceprog : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:316)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:2as
```

The jar file is created from netbeans in windows which has java version 1.8 and hadoop is running in ubuntu which had 1.6.

I thought it was a mismatch between java installed on ubuntu and the jar which is configured from a windows environment(my case), 
so I installed java 1.8 version in ubuntu and made it default.

Now the output of `java -version` and `javac -version` is as follows:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)


javac -version
javac 1.8.0_20
```

but still the problem persists.

Comment: Did you restarted your Daemons?

Comment: yeah i restarted it but it's still the same

Comment: In your $HADOOP_HOME/logs folder, you have logs can you check which java version its picking up (I used to see something like STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.6.0_33 on older version)?

Answer (score 1):

ok guys problem solved 
i forgot to change tha java home path in the conf file.

i did it and problem is gone

Comment: @JanGalinski this is the answer posted by the person who had the question.